# Problem in deriving the four-momentum with lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, momentum, velocity

Now, the Lagrangian is
$$L = -m \sqrt{-n_{ab} \frac{d\xi^{a}}{d\lambda} \frac{d\xi^{b}}{d \lambda}}.$$

In the notes i am reading, it was said that the momentum $$p_{a} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\frac{d\xi^{a}}{d\lambda})}.$$

But i am not getting the right answer, which should be, second the text, $m n_{ab}  u^{b}$.

I mean, i am getting just $p_{a} = -m(-n_{ab}\frac{d\xi^{b}}{d \lambda})^{1/2}*1/2*(\frac{d\xi^{a}}{d \lambda})^{-1/2}$

From this, i don't know how to get rid off the half, neither the $d\xi^a/d\lambda$. Am I going by the right way?

Comment: What is the four-vector $E^a$? This notation is unfamiliar to me.

Comment: @GeorgeHulsey it is the curve itself. Generally it is $\xi$, indeed, i will edit it soon.

Comment: The metric tensor should be $\eta$, not $n$.

Answer (score 1):

1. If $L = \sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu} \dot \xi^\mu \dot \xi^\nu}$, where $\dot \xi^\mu \equiv \frac{d\xi^\mu}{d\lambda}$, then
   $$p_a \equiv \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot \xi^a} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu} \dot \xi^\mu\dot \xi^\nu}} (-g_{\rho\sigma}\delta^\rho_a \dot \xi^\sigma- g_{\rho \sigma} \dot \xi^\rho \delta^\sigma_a) = -\frac{g_{a\sigma} \dot \xi^\sigma}{\sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}\dot \xi^\mu \dot \xi^\nu}}$$
   by the chain rule of elementary calculus, where we've been careful to not reuse dummy indices and where we've used that $\frac{\partial \dot \xi^\rho}{\partial \dot \xi^\sigma} = \delta^\rho_\sigma$ and that $g_{\rho\sigma}=g_{\sigma\rho}$.
2. Massive particles have normalized 4-velocities, so for on-shell trajectories $g_{\mu\nu} \dot \xi^\mu \dot \xi^\nu = -1$ (this can be verified by evaluating in a frame in which the particle is at rest).

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the 1/2 factor it means that you have not realized that
$$
{\partial~~\over\partial \dot \xi^a}\dot\xi^b=\delta_a^b.
$$
That is, the letters do not act as namespaces to identify a different variable, rather they are indexes for a particular component, or if you prefer they encode a sort of wiring diagram, “apply this covector to that vector”. It is the same $\dot\xi^\bullet$ in both cases, see? The letter may be different but when you vary the one vector field you surely also vary the other.